# Is there is any way to make the paint more smooth that the pixel is not visible?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qpainter

I'm currently try to learn making UI in python using PyQt4 library. I tried to make a server-client chatting app. when i try to make the bubble for the chat i noticed that the pixel is too obvious.

Is there is any way to make the paint more smooth that the pixel is not visible?

Below is my code if necessary

```
def paintEvent(self,event):
    painter = QPainter(self)

    painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.white, Qt.SolidPattern))
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.white, 5, Qt.SolidLine))

    start_x =50
    start_y =50
    luar = QPolygon([
        QPoint(start_x,start_y),
        QPoint(start_x+310,start_y-10),
        QPoint(start_x+274,start_y+60),
        QPoint(start_x-20,start_y+58),

        ])
    painter.drawPolygon(luar)

    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.black, Qt.SolidPattern))
    start_x +=5
    start_y +=5

    points = QPolygon([
        QPoint(start_x,start_y),
        QPoint(start_x+290,start_y-10),
        QPoint(start_x+270,start_y+50),
        QPoint(start_x-20,start_y+48),

        ])
    painter.drawPolygon(points)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the render hint to `QPainter::Antialiasing` to True with [`setRenderHint()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#setRenderHint):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)

        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.white, 5, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))

        start_pos = QtCore.QPoint(50, 50)

        luar = QtGui.QPolygon([
            QtCore.QPoint(0, 0),
            QtCore.QPoint(310, -10),
            QtCore.QPoint(274, 60),
            QtCore.QPoint(-20, 58)
            ]).translated(start_pos)

        painter.drawPolygon(luar)

        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 5, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.black, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))

        start_pos += QtCore.QPoint(5, 5)

        points = QtGui.QPolygon([
            QtCore.QPoint(0, 0),
            QtCore.QPoint(290, -10),
            QtCore.QPoint(270, 50),
            QtCore.QPoint(-20, 48)
            ]).translated(start_pos)

        painter.drawPolygon(points)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(400, 150)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Nice! this solved my problem. You even tidy up my code. Thank You!